# Can the character in my game be made up of an image from the devices camera?

Tags: ios, camera

I want to make a game where the player can take a selfie of themselves using the camera from their device and use that image as part of their character on screen. It would only be a simple platform game but wanted to ask before i start?

For IOS

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question as currently asked is not in alignment with allowable questions on stackoverflow. What have you already tried.

Comment: Nothing, its a project that i was discussing with someone today. I am fairly new to coding so was asking the feasibility from you experts first, if not then i'll have a character designed for me.

Comment: Your question is too broad and too vague to give an answer other than "yes." You'd need to do something to the image in order to make it not look really awful however, since an image from the camera could be anything, and there's no easy way to separate the user from the background.

Comment: @DuncanC Thank you and good points ... Like i say, the whole idea is new today so haven't thought to much into it, so i appreciate the response.

Answer (score 0):

yes!

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_detect_faces/ci_detect_faces.html

with this you can even detect the position of the face and crop it.(if you need)

and to make things simple. anything that other apps in the app store can do. you can do too.

Comment: Thank you SwissWiss

Comment: True enough, although the bounds rectangles you get from Core Image face detection are pretty crude, and you have to select a larger area than the crop rect to get the whole face, and run the risk of picking up parts of the background. To do a really good job of extracting faces from an image you should really use face detection followed by some sort of edge detection to find the actual borders of the user's head in order to create a reliably decent-looking game character.